# Generating array of arrays

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a Web-API method that is returning JSON and I want the array structure to look like this:
`[ [123, 1.1], [222, 3.9] ]`

My Web API controller is returning JSON in the following format:
`[{"CreatedDate":1314736440,"Reading":20.0}, "CreatedDate":1314779640,"Reading":7.9}]`

**Web API Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage AllJson()
 {
     using (var ctx = new SomeContext())
     {
         var records = ctx.DataX.ToList();
         var dtos = Mapper.Map<...>(records);
         return new HttpResponseMessage
         {
             StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
             Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtos), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
         };
     }
 }
```

**DTO**

```
public class DtoModel
    {
        public int CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public double Reading { get; set; }
    }
```

**Sample Javascipt:**

```
var seriesData = [];
        $.getJSON("api/xxx/AllJson ", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                seriesData.push(val.CreatedDate.toString() + " ," + val.Reading.toString());
                console.log(val.CreatedDate + " ," + val.Reading);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an a single array containing many arrays of length 2.

See this code:

```
 $.getJSON("api/xxx/AllJson")
            .done(function (data) {
                var processedJson = new Array();
                $.map(data, function (obj, i) {
                    processedJson.push([obj.CreatedDate, obj.Reading]);
                });

                FunctionToDoSomethingWithYourDataStructure(processedJson);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem..
structure wise, this should look like [[a,b],[c,d]];

```
var createSeriesData = function(){
    seriesData = [];
    JSON_obj = JSON.parse('[{"CreatedDate":1314736440,"Reading":20.0},{"CreatedDate":1314779640,"Reading":7.9}]');

    for(var key in JSON_obj){
        if(JSON_obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            seriesData[key] = [];
            seriesData[key].push(JSON_obj[key].CreatedDate.toString());
            seriesData[key].push(JSON_obj[key].Reading.toString());
        }

    }

    console.log(seriesData);
}
```